# Mysql Slave Claims to be Running but New Records Not Appearing and No Delay

Tags: replication, mysql-5.6, master-slave-replication, multi-master, master-master-replication

I've created a new mysql master and a slave. My master is also a slave of another running instance. The replication between those two works fine so I don't believe my issue is there.

I created a dump from the master with `master-data=1` then sent the dump to the slave and created wrote it `< file.sql`. If I run `show slave status` I get back (roughly, simplified for MVCE, if more is needed please specify):

```
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host: master_ip
Master_User: replicant_user
Master_Port: 3306
Connect_Retry: 60
Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
Read_Master_Log_Pos: 120
Relay_Log_File: ip-slave_ip-relay-bin.000004
Relay_Log_Pos: 283
Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 120
Relay_Log_Space: 512
Master_Server_Id: 2222
Master_UUID: f2c7d7a1-bb6c-11e8-a3b1-02e34d38ec08
Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
Master_Retry_Count: 86400
```

then If I do `show master status` on the master I get back:

```
File: mysql-bin.000003
Position: 120
```

which looks correct, the position and the file match. Then if I view my users:

```
select userid, username from users order by userid desc limit 30;
```

I get 28 more records on my master and the master master (master master and master counts and values match) so the slave isn't getting new records despite the `Slave_SQL_Running: Yes`.

How is this possible? I guess I did something wrong but what, where should I look?

I looked at the `mysql-bin.000003` but is says:

> Warning: this binlog is either in use or was not closed properly.

which makes sense it is the current file. I looked at the `00001` and `00002` to see if the queries I missed were in either of those files but I couldn't find them.

Comment: is `log_slave_updates` enabled on your master that is also a slave?

Comment: @danblack I get that back as `OFF`. I'm guessing I need that on, and then I'll need to re-export the DB because the records weren't logged or is there a way to recover?

Comment: Yes. An [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) is an alternative way to recover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running an intermediary replication that is also a master, `log-slave-updates` needs to be enabled to ensure that the upstream master, replicates to the downstream slave.